# Function created, but never called, yet it is still executed

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I am very new to iOS development and Swift, so sorry if this is a trivial question. I have the following code

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

    var imagePicker: UIImagePickerController!

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func openGalery(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.photoLibrary) {
            imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary;
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePicker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        imageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

In the code I create the `func imagePickerController`. `imagePickerController` is responsible for setting the selected image in the `imageView`. It works. I open the galery, I select an image and there is a transition back to the view with the image set. However, why is it working? I never call the function `imagePickerController`. Comparing this with the languages I worked before, I should call this function on tap of the select button in the `PhotoLibrary`. Like an event or something. But here it is somehow called automatically, only by defining the function. Why is that?

Comment: You are setting **imagePicker.delegate = self (Delegate)** this is the main reason that all these functions which you haven't called are executed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagePicker.delegate = self`

Translates to: "Hey `imagePicker`, when something happens, let me know by calling my `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` methods!"

In particular, your implementation of [`imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller) is being called, which is part of the [`UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate) protocol.

Comment: And I guess because of that `picker: UIImagePickerController` it knows which `ImagePicker` is referred to?

Comment: @Stophface When the picker calls the delegate methods in your `ViewController` class, it passes itself (`self`) as the first param, as the `picker` as you call it. That way, you have context as to which picker called you, exactly (in case you have multiple)

Answer (score 1):

It's **delegation pattern**.

When you set `imagePicker`'s delegate to `self`, you're starting receiving events from picker.

Events defined in `protocol`. In this case it's `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`

This pattern frequently using in iOS developing.
More about delegation pattern you can read [in Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID276)